# Freelancer Job For QA

Tags: qtp, qa-developer

I am currently working as a full time QA employee but seeking opportunity in a part time job in QA. I want to find any company or website for a part time QA job. Please suggest any.

Comment: In my opinion this board is not meant for job seeking and any answers to this question won't be useful for others in the future.

Comment: This is not a personal career advice (which is against the rules) but info about websites relevant to anyone with same goals. Should be OK and useful for others too.

Comment: Please try some freelancing websites for a job. If you have any other query or doubts about testing or need helps learning something about testing then post your questions here.

Comment: Consider http://careers.stackexchange.com - they match people across the tech industry with jobs they'll love.

Answer (score 5):

Google freelance websites.

Try freelancer.com
Elance.com
Odesk.com

And there are many other sites for such services.

Find help on forums like softwaretestingclub.com

Answer (score 3):

There are many sites like that:

- utest.com
- Amazon's mechanical Turk: https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome
- Freelancer.com
- elance.com

I got them by 15 seconds of googling for title of your question. There are more, but you get the idea.

Disclosure and warning: I never used any of them in any way, do your own research (google for reviews) before signing in.